# Select records going to expire in a month from today's date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one Oracle SQL table and field for that table is

```
id
name
date_issued
date_expire
```

I want only those records which expire within 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the items that will have expired at any time up to 30 full days from now then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_expire < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '31' DAY;
```

If you want to exclude items that have already expired then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_expire <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '31' DAY
AND    date_expire >= SYSDATE;
```

If you want to exclude items that expired before today then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_expire <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '31' DAY
AND    date_expire >= TRUNC( SYSDATE );
```

If you want to count the 30 days as today and the next 29 days then change `INTERVAL '31' DAY` to `INTERVAL '30' DAY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below one to get required result

```
 select id,name,date_issued,date_expire from yourtable 
    where date_expire between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate)+30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly 30 days expiration:

```
select * from yourtable 
    where trunc(date_expire) = trunc(sysdate)+30
```